# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Angular so bear with me.

I want to get the firstName of the current loggedin user from the firebase firestore and show it on the dashboard page. But when I try to load the dashboard, I get the following error:

```
AdminOverviewComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
at AdminOverviewComponent.push../src/app/admin/admin-overview/admin-overview.component.ts.AdminOverviewComponent.ngOnInit (admin-overview.component.ts:19)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:10097)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:11363)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:11325)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11962)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11922)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AdminOverviewComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11914)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11307)
at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
```

After this error, the firstName gets retrieved from firebase (because I console.log it). I know when the page loads, that firstName is null because of the lag fetch, but how do I solve this or what is the best way to do this?

Relevant HTML code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-dual-secondary" id="page-header-user-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  {{user}}<i class="fa fa-angle-down ml-5"></i>
              </button>
```

**admin-overview-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-overview',
  templateUrl: './admin-overview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-overview.component.css']
})
export class AdminOverviewComponent implements OnInit {

  user: string;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private userService: UserService) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.user = this.userService.userInfo.firstName;
  }

  logoutUser() {
    this.authService.logout()
  }

}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

export class UserInfo {
  Country: string;
  age: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<UserInfo>;
  public userInfo: UserInfo;
  public gotData: boolean;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore,private authService: AuthService) { 
    this.userDoc = db.doc<UserInfo>('users/' + authService.getUserUID);
    this.userDoc.valueChanges()
    .take(1)
    .subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userInfo = user;
        this.gotData = true;
      console.log("Got Data: " + user.firstName);
      }
      else {
        this.userInfo = null;
      }

    })  
  }

}
```

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of declaring `user` as a variable, you can implement it as a property getter, with a protection in case `this.userService.userInfo` is not defined:

```
get user(): string {
  return this.userService.userInfo ? this.userService.userInfo.firstName : null;
}
```

Comment: Error is gone, but the user is still not shown in the view.

Comment: How do you show it in the view? Can we see the relevant template markup? You can add a `console.log` statement in `get user()` to check if the value is OK.

Comment: added relevant HTML. console.log in get user() returns null. Calling this function in the constructor or ngOnInit() returns undefined.

Comment: You don't need to call it anywhere; the template will call it when trying to show the value in the view. If you just removed the `user` variable and defined the `get user()`, it should work. I assume that you see the correct `Got data` from the service in the console. You could add also a console.log in the `else` part of the service to check if `this.userInfo` is reset at some point.

Comment: I added an example of a console.log statement that you can put in `get user()`.

Comment: Oh I see it works! Thank! Now, when I load the page, the page loads, but the userInfo shows/loads 2-3 seconds later after the page is loaded. Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: That delay depends on the time taken to get the data from the database (you can see if `Got data` appears in the console after the same delay). I don't know how you can improve on that; it depends on your particular configuration.

Comment: I see that you are getting answers (at least one) to help showing the page after the data was loaded. I suggest that you ask a separate question for that problem. Or you can see if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50448697/1009922) will get answers that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

`<div *ngIf="user">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-dual-secondary" id="page-header-user-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{user}}<i class="fa fa-angle-down ml-5"></i></button>
</div>`

try this in your original code, it might help

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt really work for me. I already have tried this. I want the page to load after the data got loaded from firebase. I appreciate your help though!

Comment: you can use a resolver approach then, it gives the component the data required before the route has actually happened. Here is a link

https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/