# how to render html only when data from got server side

Tags: angular

I am using angular 4. I am using one div for data not found in my HTML. And I want this div should display only if data will not come. But for fetching my data it's taking time meanwhile data not found div also show, till the time data is not display. But I want to display only when data is not there.

For this, I am using below code In component.ts :

```
this.allData -> In this all data is coming but taking time.
```

Below is code in HTML file:

```
<div *ngIf="allData && allData.length > 0 else noResultFound">
This is testing data come from allData variable.
</div>
<ng-template #noResultFound>
    <h2>Sorry, no results found.</h2>
</ng-template>
```

I am facing a problem that, suppose it takes 10 seconds to fetch data, and for 10 seconds noResultFound div show. I want if should display only if data length is 0.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If `allData` is array, you can use `*ngIf="!allData.length"` and if is Object, you can try `*ngIf="!allData"`. Try that and tell me if worked! I would use `*ngIf` in two divs! One to show data and another to feedback! But I don't know if that is the best way... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty much right. You need to add a `;` before the `else` in your `ngIf`. So you html would be:

```
<div *ngIf="allData && allData.length > 0; else noResultFound">
This is testing data come from allData variable.
</div>
<ng-template #noResultFound>
    <h2>Sorry, no results found.</h2>
</ng-template>
```